# Требуется заполнить матрицу элементам, причем в каждом столбце число единиц равно номеру столбца C#

Tags: c#, массивы, матрицы

### Сформулировать случайную матрицу MxN, состоящую из нулей и единиц, причем в каждом столбце число единиц равно номеру столбца.

Никак не могу разобраться со структурой самих циклов, т.к новичок.
Надеюсь расписал все достаточно (скажите если нет).
Жду каких-либо наводок

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            matrix[y, x] = 0;
            if (y < matrix.GetLength(0) && y <= x)
            {
                for (int h = y; h >= 0; h--)
                {
                    matrix[h, x] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
         ...
         item[i,j] = 1;
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Я не понимаю) и что это значит

Comment: "Никак не могу разобраться со структурой самих циклов" - вот тебе структура циклов

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]